# How to modify computed queryset values ? (Reversed many - to - one relationship)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, many-to-one

```
class Style(Model):
    id ....
    name .... 

class Song(Model):
    ...
    style = ForgeignKey(Style, related_name="songs")

queryset = Style.objects.all()
queryset[0].songs = queryset[0].songs.filter(something=1)
#or
queryset[0].songs.set(queryset[0].songs.filter(something=1))
```

This is my actual code, but it does not work except for filtering... I would like to assigned queryset.songs new filtered songs...

or is there another way how to efficiently filter in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = Style.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('songs', Song.objects.filter(something=1))
)
```

If you access `queryset[0].songs`, you will only get the songs with `something=1`. This is of course the case for all `Style`s in the `querset`.